# Cascode Amplifier Biasing Sequence

Tags: amplifier, bias, cascode

I'm trying to understand the proper biasing procedure of a cascode distributed amplifier part that requires three power supplies. A positive drain-source VDD, a negative gate-source VGG1, and a second, positive gate-source VGG2.

[image]

The recommended biasing procedure is for the bottom MESFET VGG1 to be supplied, then the drain-source VDD, and finally the top MESFET VGG2.

I don't know much about amplifier operation, I was tasked to document the proper biasing procedure for parts and determine if there will be an issue. Case in point the VGG2 may be supplied by a linear regulator that's always on while VGG1 and VDD will be controllable. I want to understand what the ramifications of having VGG2 always being on

***EXTRA: I could also use help in trying to model the situation in ADS to have a visual representation of the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the MESFET \$\mathrm{FET_1}\$ to work in saturation region, you should require that 
$$
|V_{DS_\mathrm{FET_1}}|\ge |V_{P_\mathrm{\,FET_1}}|+|V_{GS_\mathrm{FET_1}}|, \label{1}\tag{1}
$$ 
where \$V_{P_\mathrm{\,FET_1}}\$ is the *pinch off (threshold) gate-source voltage of the* MESFET. This implies that the quiescent value of \$V_{GG_2}\$ must be chosen in such a way that \eqref{1} is satisfied, and in turn this implies that
$$
V_{GG_2}\gg V_\gamma,
$$ 
where \$V_\gamma\$ is the threshold voltage of the \$\mathrm{FET_2}\$ Gate-Source GaAs Schottky junction: normally, this is not a problem since when \$V_{DS_\mathrm{FET_1}}\$ is at its quiescent value \$V_{DSQ_\mathrm{FET_1}}\$, then 
$$
V_{GSQ_\mathrm{FET_2}}=V_{GG_2}-V_{DSQ_\mathrm{FET_1}}<0
$$
However, if you apply \$V_{GG_2}\$ before applying \$V_{GG_1}\$ then, since \$V_{DS_\mathrm{FET_1}}\$ is still nearly zero, the \$\mathrm{FET_2}\$ Gate-Source GaAs Schottky junction would became forward biased with a high value of gate current \$I_{G_\mathrm{FET_2}}\$ which would permanently damage the device: in sum *in order to avoid permanent damages to the MESFETs, it is better to follow the recommended biasing sequence*.

Comment: Is it possible use a negative Vss1 so you can cascade Vdd2 at the same DC voltage to the next Vgg in to make a distributed amplifier?  Or is DC biasing isolated between stages

Comment: Since \$V_{GSQ_\mathrm{FET_1}}\$ is usually <0 for MESFETs, it is possible to use a *positive* \$V_{SS_1}\$ instead of a negative \$V_{GG_1}\$: to my knowledge, DC biasing between RF/MW stages, need not to be isolated. However, years ago  \$V_{SS}\$ biasing was not advocated because it was difficult to realize a source decoupling network with adequate low impedance at high frequency: this was especially true for low noise stages.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Thank you very much for your response and breaking it down for me. I understand to an extent where I feel I can document the issue and go forward with looking at options to fix it.

Comment: @aj_intern2019 You are welcome. And if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting and accepting it.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri I have upvoted and accepted your answer. I do not have enough points for the upvote to display however. But again I appreciate your response. Have a nice day.

Comment: @aj_intern2019 it does not matter: I am happy to have been of some help. Thank you.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I apologize for not putting your address in the answer to the question in your comment above: I am trying to remedy by this comment.